# IText7 pdf2Data it is compatible with c# core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, itext, itext7, pdf2data

I'm developing an application, but the PdfiumViewer library (2.13.0) inside the incompatibility module. showing the error:

**NU1701    Package 'PdfiumViewer 2.13.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.**

An easy solution?

Comment: What happened when you tried it? Did it run? Did it work?

Comment: Nothing, do not compile the code.

Comment: NU1701 Package 'PdfiumViewer 2.13.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.



Some classes have also not been imported into the code, such as ** Pdf2DataExtractor **

Comment: iText's pdf2data is available both in Java and C#.

Please follow the guide which can be found on iText's webpage: https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/installation-guides/installing-itext-7-pdf2data-net-developers

Comment: Have you contacted iText support already?

Answer (score 2):

I believe its not compatible with .Net Core/Standard.

Pdf2Data has a dependency on PdfiumViewer which appears to only work on Framework.